# Como executar o metodo dentro de um arquivo.py pelo terminal linux

Tags: python, linux, terminal, flask

Como posso realizar a chamada de um método que está dentro de um arquivo.py diretamente pelo terminal do linux, só que não quero entrar no `prompt` do `python`
Por exemplo

```
[fedora@user ~]$ python arquivo.py metodo parametro
```

Algo parecido com o `manage.py` do Django/Python

Comment: pelo terminal linux, vc quer dizer rodando um bash?

Comment: isso mesmo, a idéia é criar um `arquivo.py` para criação de diretórios e arquivos padrões!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para executar um método especifico dentro do arquivo, as soluções propostas até agora estão corretas, mas acho que o que você procura é algo mais parecido com [Python Command Line Arguments](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm), que é o que é usado no `manage.py` do django.

Segue um exemplo de como implementar um caso bem simples:

```
import sys

def metodo1(param1):
    print("O metodo 1 recebeu o parametro '{0}'".format(param1))

def metodo2(param1, param2):
    print("O metodo 2 recebeu os parametros '{0}' e '{1}'".format(param1, param2))

qual_metodo_usar = sys.argv[1]

if qual_metodo_usar == "metodo1":
    parametro1 = sys.argv[2]
    metodo1(parametro1)
elif qual_metodo_usar == "metodo2":
    parametro1 = sys.argv[2]
    parametro2 = sys.argv[3]
    metodo2(parametro1, parametro2)
else:
    print("Metodo desconhecido")
```

Exemplos de entrada e saída:

```
python met.py metodo1 teste
```

> O metodo 1 recebeu o parametro 'teste'

```
python met.py metodo2 ola mundo
```

> O metodo 2 recebeu os parametros 'ola' e 'mundo'

Comment: Isso mesmo, muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 1):

> Editada
>   Quando respondi foquei estritamente na questão em si, mas depois vi nos comentários que a intenção do autor é fazer algo parecido com `devops` ou gerenciamento de infra utilizando o python, e então vi que a melhor resposta é a do @jsbueno e, para complementar, resolvi editar minha resposta com um exemplo (prototipo) do `argpasse` que ele cita

createdir.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Script para criacao de diretorios e arquivos padroes!')    
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose',action="store_true", help="verbose output" )    
parser.add_argument('-R', action="store_false",  
    help="Copia recursiva de todos os arquivos e diretorios")    
parser.add_argument('dirname', type=str, help="Diretorio a ser criado")    
parser.add_argument('filename', type=argparse.FileType('w'),
     help="Arquivo a ser criado")    

args = parser.parse_args()
print (args)

## Implemente o resto daqui em diante
```

Agora vamos tornar o script executável:

```
$ chomd +x createdir.py
```

Após isso teste na linha de comando, por causa da primeira linha `#!/usr/bin/python` não é necessário chamar o pyton, vc pode chamar o script diretamente:

```
$./createdir -h
```

**Saida:**

```
Script para criacao de diretorios e arquivos padroes!

positional arguments:
  dirname        Diretorio a ser criado
  filename       Arquivo a ser criado

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose  verbose output
  -R             Copia recursiva de todos os arquivos e diretorios
```

Agora vamos chamar com argumentos, veja q no final do script ha um comando para dar um print nos mesmos.

```
~/createdir.py -R /home/admin arquivo1
Namespace(R=False, dirname='/home/admin', filename=<open file 'arquivo1', 
mode 'w' at 0x7f632dc47300>, verbose=False)
```

> A partir deste ponto a resposta "original":

Para exemplificar vamos criar um arquivo chamada `hello.py` com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
def hello():
    print ('hello world!')

def foo():
    print ('bar')
```

Agora vamos chamar a função `foo` dentro de hello.py

```
$ python -c 'import hello; hello.foo()'
bar
```

E agora a função hello:

```
$ python -c 'import hello; hello.hello()'
hello world!
```

Answer (score 1):

O melhor é escrever o seu programa em Python de forma que ele implemente os parâmetros de que necessite na sintaxe mais usada em programas de linha de comando. Aí, você marca seu arquivo Python como executável, e pode usar o mesmo como usa qualquer outro comando a partir do bash.

Aqui tem o tutorial do argparse:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html#id1

Agora, se o script está pronto,com as funções que você quer e você não vai nem mexer nele, nem escrever um script auxiliar pra importar o original e implementar as switches de linhas de comando, pode usar o Python com a opção "-c" para executar expressões separadas por ";" - aí, a primeira expressão é importar o seu script de Python, e a segunda, chamar sua função.

```
python -c "import meuarquivo; meuarquivo.minha_funcao()"
```

E na chamada de "minha_funcao()" você pode colocar variávei do BASH prefixadas com $ para passar parâmetros literais - mas não esqueça de que
se forem string, devem estar dentro de aspas no código em Python. 
(E aí você tem que tomar cuidado por que tem que colocar aspas duplas para o BASH passar sua linha de Python como um único parâmetro para o interpretador Python e aspas simples dentro do parênteses

```
nome=Joao
python -c "print('$nome')"
```